# How to apply a OR filter on same field with different values in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, aws-elasticsearch

I am looking to add a filter on the same field with different values.
Basically i want to get the docs with filter of type **mode1 or mode2**. Something is wrong in the below query.

```
 {
   "index": "abcdef*",
   "from": 0,
   "size": 50,
   "body": {
   "query": {
     "bool": {
         "must": [{ "term": { "id": "123455" } }],
         "filter": [{ "term": { "mode": "mode1" } }, { "term": { "mode": "mode2" } }]
     }
   } 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to move `bool/should` at the top level and use `bool/filter` instead of `bool/must` for the term query (as you don't need relevance, just a yes/no answer for the constraint on the `id` field):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mode": "mode1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "mode": "mode2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "123455"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or even better, simply leverage the `terms` query which makes the query as simple as it gets:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "123455"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "mode": ["mode1", "mode2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the first approach it worked. Will check the 2nd one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause along with the `filter` clause

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "123455"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "mode": "mode1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "mode": "mode2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use nested bool query and apply should clause which acts like OR query.

```
{
  "index": "abcdef*",
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "id": "123455"
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "mode": "mode1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "mode": "mode2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I think we posted same time :D

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth This DSL is not optimal ;-)